# fetching data from database in randomly generated button

Tags: php

i found it difficult,,,, fetching data from database while a buttons are randomly generated in for each  how can i fetch

Comment: This does not really make much sense, are you saying you have buttons that are created in a loop and each button should submit queries to the database? Your code would be a great start

Comment: You need to clarify yourself a bit more. Have you got any code, examples or something that would show what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Without understanding what your question really is, you could go trough the mysql query result like this:

```
// button_text is a database column in this example

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    echo "<button type="button">".$row['button_text']."</button>"; 
}
```

But to really help you, you need to rephrase your question!

Answer (score 1):

I'll make some assumptions for what you are trying to do:
1. You have buttons that fetch more info from a db
2. The buttons are "randomly" generated, and each calls different info (pets, cars, etc).

You may or may not be using ajax, but I will describe it basically assuming straight php, and you are using a single page (for clarity in my explanation).

What you need to do is have each button either be a link or a submit for a form. This just depends on whether you want to use GET or POST. The buttons will have php generated links (if GET) or values (if POST). For example, using get the link could be "www.file.php?cat=cars". The button would just have the value of "Cars", and since bother are generated, that shouldn't be an issue keeping them the same.

When the page is now reloaded based on the click, the top of the page has a query in it to get the new info. For example, it would run a query looking for all items that have the car category. Then the new information would be displayed, and the new random buttons would show.

VERY IMPORTANT: Sanitize all GET and POST values before using them in a query